# python - How to set column as index in a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

**Given below is my current pandas DataFrame:**

```
         Balance before Salary   Salary
Month                                 
Jun-18                  27.20  15300.0
Jul-18                  88.20  15300.0
Aug-18                 176.48  14783.0
Sep-18                  48.48  16249.0
Oct-18                 241.48  14448.0
Nov-18                  49.48  15663.0
```

**is it possible to convert the above DataFrame in the below format?**

```
                        Month1  Month2  Month3  Month4  Month5  Month6
Balance before Salary   27.2    88.2    176.48  48.48   241.48  49.48
Salary                 15300    15300   14783   16249   14448   15663
```

**Code**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(salary_List)
newdf = df.groupby('date').sum()
newdf = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1M')).sum()
newdf.index = newdf.index.strftime('%b-%y')
newdf.index.name = 'Month'
```

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Do you need `transpose` ? `df = df.T` ?

Comment: How to change the column heading to Month1 Month2 etc..?

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need `transpose` by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) and then if necessary change column names add list comprehension:

*Notice:*
*Double `groupby+sum` is not necessary, once is enough, because aggregate same aggregate function, here `sum`.*

```
df = pd.DataFrame(salary_List)

newdf = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1M')).sum().T
#python 3.6+
newdf.columns = [f'Month{x}' for x in range(1, len(newdf.columns) + 1)]

#python bellow
#newdf.columns = ['Month{}'.format(x) for x in range(1, len(newdf.columns) + 1)]
print (newdf)
                        Month1   Month2    Month3    Month4    Month5  \
Balance before Salary     27.2     88.2    176.48     48.48    241.48   
Salary                 15300.0  15300.0  14783.00  16249.00  14448.00   

                         Month6  
Balance before Salary     49.48  
Salary                 15663.00
```

Comment: Nice use of column name formatting. :) +1 from me, pl have a look at my method too, got an idea. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is called 'transpose'.
You can get the transposed dataframe by calling the `df.transpose()` function.
So for you simply :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(salary_List)
newdf = df.transpose()
```

Then with a simple loop you may change the column names to the ones yoyu want.

Answer (score 1):

You an also get the Month and Year(for better clarity) and then transpose:

resetting the index to get the Month as a column:

```
df1 = df1.rename_axis('Month').reset_index()
df1.drop([0],inplace=True)
```

Then:

```
df['Month'] = df['Month'].apply( lambda x : pd.to_datetime(x).strftime('%b %Y')) # gets name of month and year
df_new = df1.T #transpose and save to new df
df_new.columns = df_new.iloc[0] # set columnnames as monthnames
df_new.drop('Month',inplace=True) # drop the extra row Month
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yes, but OP have a bit different input data, so your solution not working. Input data are column `date` fille by datetimes, so working `newdf = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1M')).sum()` very nice. Output of first DataFrame is after `newdf.index.name = 'Month'`

Comment: I tested this with the same data that the OP has given, seems to work for me.

Comment: Sure, but `Given below is my current pandas DataFrame:` is after paragraph of code `df = pd.DataFrame(salary_List)
newdf = df.groupby('date').sum()
newdf = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1M')).sum()
newdf.index = newdf.index.strftime('%b-%y')
newdf.index.name = 'Month'`

Comment: got it, i had the `Month` as a column.